# Django 1.4 Local 500 Error Page

Tags: django

Since moving to Django 1.4 with DEBUG = True and TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True, I no longer see the typical yellow error screen with traceback when I encounter an error locally. Instead I get a plain white screen that says, "An error has occurred. Please check your logs . . . ". Is this the new behavior or have I screwed something up by combining 1.3 and 1.4 files and settings.

Here's an [example of my local settings.](http://pastebin.com/icAgiKeS)

Comment: You must have a problem elsewhere, because the traceback detail page is still very much a part of django 1.4 DEBUG mode

Comment: How would I run that down? I see the proper error info in the localhost server. Am I causing a conflict by using STATIC_URL but keeping MEDIA_URLS? I've updated the post with a link to example settings.

Comment: And you're using `python manage.py runserver`? The `runserver` management command doesn't keep logs, so your error seems to indicate you're running an actual webserver.

Comment: Yes, just the simple runserver command.

Comment: My remark won't help you, probably, but you have set `MEDIA_ROOT` twice in your settings file. Is this on purpose? Maybe this causes a conflict?

Comment: Do you have `handler500` defined in root urlconf? It shouldn't be considered when `DEBUG=True` but you can check that part.

Comment: How did you install 1.4?  Have you tried your code in a clean virtual env with Django 1.4 installed?  If you run `python manage.py shell` and import and query your models etc., do you encounter errors?

Comment: This is happening in multiple clean virtualenvs. I do have a handler50 defined, doesn't seem to apply with DEBUG=True. MEDIA_ROOT is defined twice because I've pasted my main settings.py and some local settings together, but I will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error handler 
is located in django.core.handler.base try to debug the handle_uncaught_exception function.

```
def handle_uncaught_exception(self, request, resolver, exc_info):
    """
    Processing for any otherwise uncaught exceptions (those that will
    generate HTTP 500 responses). Can be overridden by subclasses who want
    customised 500 handling.

    Be *very* careful when overriding this because the error could be
    caused by anything, so assuming something like the database is always
    available would be an error.
    """
    from django.conf import settings

    if settings.DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS:
        raise

    logger.error('Internal Server Error: %s', request.path,
        exc_info=exc_info,
        extra={
            'status_code': 500,
            'request': request
        }
    )

    if settings.DEBUG:
        from django.views import debug
```

> > check if you pass here
> >                 return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)

```
    # If Http500 handler is not installed, re-raise last exception
    if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
        raise exc_info[1], None, exc_info[2]
    # Return an HttpResponse that displays a friendly error message.
    callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve500()
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
```

check with the debugger that you pass in debug.technical_500_response

Comment: Argh, you got me to the fix. For some reason when working on [changing my project skeleton code](https://bitbucket.org/tclancy/deployment/changeset/06d72a3c12d8c1b2a1e9fa09e27e19be151a2f98#chg-DjangoDefaults/project/local_settings.py), I added DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True to my settings but I managed to not paste that in when I munged my example file together on Pastebin. Bug summary: I am a moron. Thanks.